# Удаление вируса

Tags: windows, вирусы

Ребят, кто сталкивался с блокировкой страниц из-за спама в социальных сетях? На компе вирус, не пропускает ни с одного браузера, удаляла вручную из `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc` не помогло, антивирусником бесполезно...

Comment: Что за вирь? что за антиВирь? Что удаляли? Пободробнее бы....P.S. Странно... На Ubunt-е такого не замечал... (шутка)

Comment: Чистила файл hosts...Обычно, когда такая проблема возникала, этого хватало...Но из-за массовой рассылки спама сайт заблокировали и, есесьно, требуют номер тел.У всех, кто вводит логин и пароль с этого компа, ломаются страницы на ура...в сеть не допускает, а вот спам рассылается со страшной силой.Антивирь AVG.

Comment: Ну как один из вариантов, LiveCD у Каспера или Др.Веба.(на сайте у них свободно, не сможете найти, скину ссылки).С этих же LiveCD можно инет настроить и войти в соц.сеть, посмотреть как себя вести будет.

Comment: Пробовала конеш и livеcd...никаких результатов...

Comment: Что msconfig про автозагрузку говорит? Лишние службы не висят?> Пробовала конеш и livеcd...никаких результатов...Что именно пробовали? Просто попробовать зайти в соц.сеть не поможет, из-под лцд надо систему лечить... А уже ПОСЛЕ того как система вылечена - разбираться с администрацией сайтов чтоб разлочили... А, кстати, что амины говорят? Письмо им писАли?

Comment: Nika, может проще организовать удаленный доступ на ваш комп, например тимвьювером, и уже "вживую" посмотреть. Извините, если мое предложение покажется бестактным.ЗЫhttp://www.kaspersky.ru/virusscanner выбрать Kaspersky Rescue DiskЭто образ, закатать на диск и запустить. Из под системы рекомендую AVZ (z-oleg.com) раздел Download

Answer (score 1):

1. Прежде чем **физически** удалить вирус, необходимо его хотя бы убрать из памяти. Нынче вирусы наглые пошли - просто так себя удалять не дают (а некоторые и прячутся очень сильно).
2. Необходимо понять, где именно вирус стартует и исключить возможности для его запуска.
3. Сами вирусы не сидят в файле hosts - они могут там лишь прописать какие-то свои адреса для творения гадостей. Хотя можно им тоже напакостить - сделать файл только на чтение.
4. Возможно этот вирус легко определяется и удаляется при загрузке в Safe Mode. Но не факт.
5. В крайнем случае снимите винт и пройдитесь по нему антивирусником на чистой, незараженной, машине.
6. НИКОГДА НЕ РАБОТАЙТЕ В АДМИНИСТРАТИВНОМ РЕЖИМЕ для того, чтобы гулять по сети.
7. AVZ в помощь - что сидит в памяти, что где стартует и т.п.

Но вообще с вирусами - как в детективе. Ищешь, выслеживаешь, изничтожаешь. Универсального метода нет :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте обновить кеш, откройте командную строку и пропишите,

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

и ребутнитесь.